if $x_n \longrightarrow 0$, then $(a,b)= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a + x_n, b-x_n] $
If $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of positive extended real numbers for wich:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n=0$,

then, given $a,b \in closure(\mathbb{R})=[- \infty, \infty]$ with $a \leq b$, it seems to be true that:

$(a,b] = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(a, b + x_n) =\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a+ x_n, b]$;

$[a,b) = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(a-x_n,b)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a,b- x_n)$;

$(a,b) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(a, b-x_n]= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a + x_n, b-x_n]  = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a+x_n,b)$;


since it is valid for $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$.
First question: is that really the case? And if so, then would be the case that:

$(a,b)= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a + x_n, b-y_n] $, where $y_n \longrightarrow 0$ ?

Second question: Would there be a more generalization idea of this fact? Is there any other property not mentioned that is valid?

You write $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,b_n]= (a,b)$ in the title and $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,b_n]= (a,b)$ in the question body. Both statements are wrong (consider constant sequences).

sorry martin, i'll correct it.

You need to impose that $x_n > 0$. Otherwise the union will be $[a, b]$ not $(a, b)$ as Martin says

already edited, thank you George

I will give a proof of the first one, the rest are similar. Impose $x_n > 0$ for each $n$ (and I suppose we should have $a + x_n \le b - x_n$ for all $n$ too). We first have $b + x_n > b > a$ for each $n$, so $(a, b] \subseteq (a, b + x_n)$ for each $n$ and:
$$(a, b] \subseteq \bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty (a, b + x_n)$$
Then suppose that $y \in (a, b + x_n)$ for each $n$. We then have the inequality:
$$a < y < b + x_n$$
for each $n$.
Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $x_n \to 0$, for large enough $n$ (say $n \ge N$), we have $x_n < \epsilon$ and so $a < y < b + \epsilon$. Since this holds for $\epsilon > 0$ you can intuitively reason that we should now have $a < y \le b$ (that is, $y \in (a, b]$), but we can quickly prove it. Suppose not and that $y > b$. Then we would have $y - b > 0$, and so taking $\epsilon = y - b$ we would have $y < y$, a contradiction.
It is in general true that if a sequence $(x_n)$ has $x_n \to a$ while satisfying the bounds $c < x_n < d$, we have $c \le a \le d$.

Hi George: In the very last expression,  did you mean $c \le a \le d$ ?

oh yeah oops @markleeds
